# Weekly SEDE refresh may be stuck restoring Literature.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I'm [again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382155/307535) looking at [rene's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) SEDE query [Status of the SEDE Refresh on Sunday 03:00 UTC](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc) to check the status, which is currently (in part):

| . | category | database_id | Description | create_date | days ago |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | restoring | 211 | StackExchange.Literature_Temp | 2023-04-16 03:12:49 | 0 |

... which is about 10 hours before I write this. I do hope nothing is -- or was -- [on fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Alexandria#Burning_by_Julius_Caesar)!

This particular problem seems to be [DISTINCT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93158/how-to-speed-up-select-distinct) from the [most recent issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385969/the-current-sede-refresh-was-delayed-overnight) of a failure on a backup share that caused the process to be disabled, since there's evidence of previous restoration activity:

| . | category | database_id | Description | create_date | days ago |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | days group start | 11 | # databases 42 | 2023-04-16 03:09:39 | 0 |
| 2 | newest | 210 | StackExchange.Literature.Meta | 2023-04-16 03:12:48 | 0 |

Comment: Yeah, happens to often. :(

Comment: I've heard it said: software eventually works; hardware eventually fails!

Comment: Also, really hope Aaron isn't on vacation, he's the only one who handle such cases. If he's away, it's going to be very long wait until SEDE will be updated for the stuck site. (and it might also cause the whole process to fail, making SEDE not refreshing at all.)

Comment: So, SEDE got stuck in a good book?

Comment: @AaronBertrand sadly it's still bugged, it added few records yesterday around 6pm but that's it, nothing else, and there are posts edited today. ([Query, it sorts by last activity](https://data.stackexchange.com/literature/query/1739074/check-latest-records-for-lit-se))

Comment: @Shadow The Literature database was restored successfully in SEDE at 2023-04-16 23:42:34.467 UTC. So it can't possibly be expected to contain posts edited today.

Comment: @AaronBertrand ohh, oops. Well, it appears Drones is now stuck, are you aware?

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Yes.

Comment: @AaronBertrand but what's going on? Why the job get stuck so often? Is this some bug in the code, or something in the database itself?

Comment: It was a schema change in all databases that went out on Friday afternoon. A column was made NULLable and then some NULL values were added in a few databases, and SEDE wasn't prepared to let that column have NULL values. We're working on it, you need to give us time to solve the problem before we can give you a full debrief. :-)

Comment: I tried searching Meta.SE ([recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)) and [Literature.Meta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/) for hints (remembering that schema changes have broken SEDE in the past), but came up empty. Good old Friday afternoon changes -- gotta watch those! :)  Hope it's an easy fix!

Comment: @JeffSchaller This change had to do with letting us disassociate a user from being the owner of a tag synonym. I doubt that type of change rose to the level of meta announcement, and obviously nobody involved predicted any downstream impact to SEDE. Also it didn't involve Literature specifically except in a data sense, so you wouldn't find anything on its meta, either. It was just the _first_ database where the issue happened, and stopped the job; the next database where the issue happened was Drones.

Comment: @AaronBertrand aka fixing bugs cause more bugs. :D

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Always.

Comment: Its ---turtles--- bugs all the way down?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Really, really, really TL;DR**:

This has been fixed.

**TL;DR:**

The source of the problem was a schema change<sup>*</sup> to allow `NULL` values for `TagSynonyms.OwnerUserId`. Previously, we internally weren't able to disassociate a (say, deleted) user from being the owner of a tag synonym, because we couldn't change the column value to `NULL`. This change (in combination with data changes in the meantime) caused some of the databases in the SEDE process to fail. The two databases observed here were `Literature` and `Drones`, but there were others.

> <sup>*</sup> *I joked in the comments about Friday afternoon releases, but had this specific change been shipped on Monday morning or Tuesday at lunch, we still would have had the same result over the weekend.*

**Background**:

The process of populating the SEDE databases is that in the production database we have a set of views, one for each table we copy over to SEDE. We use views because we don't necessarily need all of the columns for any given table, or we want to change the name of the table (e.g. `PostsWithDeleted`), or the order of the columns, or what have you. So normally the process looks like this:

[image: Normal populate SEDE process]

As [I've written about recently here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7598/refresh-sql-server-view-when-underlying-tables-are-modified/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), changes to underlying tables can cause the views that reference them to have stale / inaccurate metadata. Usually this involves adding, dropping, or renaming columns, or changing the data type, and usually it is also accompanied by views that erroneously use `SELECT *`. In this case, the view does *not* use `SELECT *`, and the only thing that changed was whether the column allows `NULL` (from `no` to `yes`), a less common change, but still vulnerable. So when the SEDE process ran and generated a new table based on the metadata of the *view*, the view still thought the column was not nullable, so the generated destination table had that column defined as `NOT NULL`:

[image: SEDE process after schema change]

When it started loading data from the source table, though, in a few databases, it encountered `NULL` values, and raised this exception (which made a lot more sense after unpeeling the entire onion):

> `Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL`

In the previous version of the code, this failure halts the job, and it goes no further. I've updated the code to skip past any such failures, which allowed the job to process the rest of the databases to minimize the delay. I corrected the problematic ones in the meantime, by running `sp_refreshsqlmodule` against the `TagSynonyms` view in the source database; then, I processed those ones again manually, and this time the destination column allowed `NULL`. (As an aside, this manual part is why `Drones` is the newest database, instead of the usual `StackOverflow`.)

Nobody involved with reviewing the PR (myself included) anticipated the downstream effect on SEDE. We've certainly added it to our internal "lessons learned" documentation.

I've got discussion items queued up for how we'll avoid this in the future, including whether we should just refresh *all* of the SEDE views after *any* schema change or, more simply, prior to the weekly SEDE process.

Comment: Is there a relevant post or chat message for the ability to dissociate users from tag synonyms?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog There's no functional change to how tag synonyms work. There's no disassociation, but now we maintain better data integrity by not keeping ids of deleted users in the synonyms table.

Comment: As is becoming tradition, your answer to this post is a phenomenal breakdown of what went wrong. Thank you for the care in which you take when writing them, I can assure you that it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Spevacus Thanks! I really don't like when companies gloss over and hand-wave what went wrong and how they fixed it, so I like to report on the issue the way I'd want to read about it. Finding the right balance of too much detail or not enough can be hard at scale, but I think I have a decent handle on the audience here. :-)

Comment: @Spevacus sadly, he's the only one, or one of very few. :(